# Using Twimlbin and adding in a Prepared mp3 voicemail

Tags: mp3, twilio, voicemail

I am a new user to **Twilio** and found **Twimlbin** which seems to work good except for the issue of voicemail with a prepared mp3.

I want it to simulring 2 of my phone numbers and if no one picks up to follow the voicemail route.  I want a mp3 file that I created be the voicemail that the caller hears.  Everything is considered valid until I try to add in my mp3 file so I am not sure if I am putting in the wrong place or it is formatted improperly.  I have attached the code that works and then the one where i add the mp3 and get it to be invalid.

**WITHOUT MP3 and works fine:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="7085551212" timeout="10">
    <Number url="http://twimlbin.com/95e18da6">5551232248</Number>
     <Number url="http://twimlbin.com/95e18da6">5551232249</Number>
</Dial>
  <Redirect>http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=email@yahoo.com</Redirect></Response>
```

**WITH MP3 and does is invalid per Twimlbin**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="7085551212" timeout="10">
    <Number url="http://twimlbin.com/95e18da6">5551232248</Number>
    <Number url="http://twimlbin.com/95e18da6">5551232249</Number>
</Dial>
  <Redirect>http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=email@yahoo.com&Message=http://www.website.com/twilio/test1.mp3&Transcribe=false&</Redirect></Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you're trying to Simulring, what you should use is [this](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/simulring) instead. What it will do, is add the MP3 file to the dial tag as the `FailUrl` attribute, and still have the timeout of 10 seconds as you wanted.

Your dial tag should then look like this:

```
<Dial callerId="7085551212" timeout="10" Dial=true&FailUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Ftwilio%2Ftest1.mp3">
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was looking for something a little more complicated than just simulring after really looking at the steps I wanted to accomplish. I wanted to use Twimlbin as my way of getting it done.

So I wanted the call to be simultaneously be ringing two phones at the same time.  When someone picked up you would get a "whisper" message.  If you chose to take the call great the phone call came through.  If you were not available at all or you did not want to take the call (clicking your end button on the cell) I wanted it to go to voicemail with my own greeting.  Also, I had the number of the business show up as the caller ID as opposed to the true caller's number.

I found a post after after some searching that was on the right track but I tweaked it a little.  It is a two step process but here is what I did:

Twimlbin1 (Whisper for the simulring on both phones)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>You have a call coming in for "Business Name".  I will connect you now.
</Say>
</Response>
```

I then added in the other functionality that I was looking for with the second one and nested the first into the second.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Response>
<Dial callerId="9999999999" timeout="10">
    <Number url="http://twimlbin.com/95d18ab5">1111111111</Number>
        <Number url="http://twimlbin.com/95d18ab5">2222222222</Number>

</Dial>
<Redirect>http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=email%40yahoo.com&amp;Message=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2Fvoicemail.mp3&amp;Transcribe=false     </Redirect>
```

Hope this helps another person out with a little complex issue like mine.

Mike